# Using PHP variable in Select MSQL query and it returns Error

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am new to PHP and MySQL and I am trying to use PHP Variable as name of table. But when I do that it returns :

> SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '321321' at line 1

My code is :

```
$dbname = "321321";
require_once('authenticate.php');
$ownerID =  $_SESSION["accNumber"];
if($dbname != $ownerID){
    header('Location: login.php');
}


$db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'root'; // Username
$db_pass = '***'; // Password
$db_name = 'test_database'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}



$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$dbname.'';
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: `321321` is not a valid database name

Comment: You probably mean to use `$db_name`, not `$dbname`

Comment: @ishegg There are two variables `$dbname` and `$db_name` in the question.

Comment: @Syscall I know, and only the second one looks like the one he wants to use (it’s grouped with the other, has a comment explaining what it is, etc)

Comment: @ishegg Yes, but the OP already used `$db_name` in the connection, so no point in an additional `use` statement, right?

Comment: @RacilHilan I just now realized this is about the database name, not the table name. Got confused. I think OP might have those confused as well... if he only came back and replied :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add backticks `` ` `` around your table name, because it doesn't begin by a letter :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `'.$dbname.'`';
```

As pointed by @RacilHilan (see comment below), it would be better to rename the table to avoid this kind of confusions.

Comment: In that case, I would also recommend renaming the variable to `$table_name` for clarity.

Comment: @RacilHilan You're right. I'll add it into the answer. Thank you.